# Age stratified analysis in R

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, contingency-tables, stratification

I am working on a project for which I need to do age stratified analysis for age of onset, age at last visit to the hospital and age at death. Our collaborator wants me to create an "Age stratified table per status (1,2,3)  stratified by cohort". What does she actually mean and how do I do this in R?

```
    tt <- structure(list(iid = structure(c(`4367` = 41L, `15178` = 31L, 
`803` = 33L, `7231` = 44L, `3314` = 99L, `6567` = 3L, `11534` = 37L, 
`11544` = 38L, `5371` = 87L, `15551` = 55L, `15391` = 45L, `14921` = 17L, 
`15665` = 65L, `14068` = 49L, `9859` = 5L, `9353` = 86L, `7324` = 47L, 
`10566` = 9L, `6686` = 19L, `12009` = 70L, `14927` = 18L, `14565` = 79L, 
`5654` = 95L, `13417` = 94L, `6817` = 23L, `3028` = 52L, `4108` = 20L, 
`17234` = 84L, `8051` = 74L, `13970` = 43L, `17705` = 64L, `12823` = 50L, 
`5180` = 27L, `12413` = 22L, `4861` = 73L, `16204` = 92L, `17781` = 72L, 
`8091` = 76L, `13260` = 78L, `16577` = 30L, `2947` = 40L, `12549` = 29L, 
`6698` = 21L, `1921` = 90L, `16931` = 63L, `1715` = 77L, `13552` = 12L, 
`233` = 67L, `14184` = 57L, `8058` = 75L, `14137` = 51L, `2311` = 24L, 
`5323` = 82L, `4644` = 39L, `6574` = 4L, `17585` = 35L, `16978` = 66L, 
`13097` = 68L, `1034` = 46L, `17359` = 93L, `11186` = 11L, `16289` = 96L, 
`3544` = 56L, `17221` = 80L, `17241` = 85L, `15320` = 42L, `10361` = 8L, 
`1179` = 53L, `14696` = 89L, `14240` = 61L, `13281` = 81L, `188` = 60L, 
`8918` = 48L, `4295` = 100L, `13565` = 14L, `9686` = 1L, `7499` = 54L, 
`9813` = 2L, `13569` = 16L, `8581` = 13L, `11029` = 10L, `16300` = 97L, 
`12477` = 25L, `9374` = 88L, `9036` = 59L, `13522` = 98L, `10031` = 7L, 
`821` = 34L, `10016` = 6L, `11970` = 69L, `6923` = 26L, `13808` = 32L, 
`9402` = 91L, `14592` = 83L, `8781` = 36L, `2527` = 28L, `4597` = 15L, 
`4885` = 62L, `1247` = 58L, `5828` = 71L), .Label = c("09AD15049", 
"09AD16760", "09AD16914_NACC082679", "09AD16934_NACC444662", 
"09AD17380", "09AD18901", "09AD18925", "09AD19739", "09AD20369", 
"10AD23300", "27564", "NACC006109", "NACC006368", "NACC017525", 
"NACC022113", "NACC024542", "NACC025848", "NACC031468", "NACC035702_08AD11678", 
"NACC038726", "NACC039815_09AD14641", "NACC079667", "NACC105660_08AD11689", 
"NACC119655", "NACC135096", "NACC151854_08AD7757", "NACC171578", 
"NACC183751", "NACC191953", "NACC193689", "NACC195165", "NACC209283", 
"NACC224051", "NACC234892", "NACC246522", "NACC250984", "NACC256669", 
"NACC266210", "NACC286235", "NACC293642", "NACC302216", "NACC306292", 
"NACC322567", "NACC333589_09AD13683", "NACC347611", "NACC358132", 
"NACC380482_08AD8144", "NACC386821", "NACC392815", "NACC417504", 
"NACC448017", "NACC456139", "NACC459177", "NACC466486_08AD10812", 
"NACC472939", "NACC483309", "NACC484535", "NACC492224", "NACC510923", 
"NACC512892", "NACC514998", "NACC522588", "NACC522704", "NACC529473", 
"NACC553874", "NACC575784", "NACC618811", "NACC636234", "NACC670026", 
"NACC708345", "NACC717532", "NACC722553", "NACC726530", "NACC735204_08AD11164", 
"NACC737878_08AD11016", "NACC752488_08AD7749", "NACC753447", 
"NACC770057", "NACC780374", "NACC788939", "NACC794979", "NACC795252", 
"NACC795728", "NACC799353", "NACC804511", "NACC842938", "NACC843642", 
"NACC864182", "NACC864553", "NACC889512", "NACC893727", "NACC896900", 
"NACC898988", "NACC907646", "NACC956562", "NACC963831", "NACC971672", 
"NACC982981", "NACC984280", "NACC992021"), class = "factor"), 
    cohort = structure(c(`4367` = 2L, `15178` = 8L, `803` = 12L, 
    `7231` = 1L, `3314` = 2L, `6567` = 1L, `11534` = 5L, `11544` = 5L, 
    `5371` = 2L, `15551` = 8L, `15391` = 8L, `14921` = 8L, `15665` = 8L, 
    `14068` = 7L, `9859` = 4L, `9353` = 3L, `7324` = 1L, `10566` = 4L, 
    `6686` = 1L, `12009` = 5L, `14927` = 8L, `14565` = 7L, `5654` = 2L, 
    `13417` = 6L, `6817` = 1L, `3028` = 2L, `4108` = 2L, `17234` = 9L, 
    `8051` = 1L, `13970` = 7L, `17705` = 10L, `12823` = 6L, `5180` = 2L, 
    `12413` = 6L, `4861` = 2L, `16204` = 8L, `17781` = 10L, `8091` = 1L, 
    `13260` = 6L, `16577` = 9L, `2947` = 2L, `12549` = 6L, `6698` = 1L, 
    `1921` = 12L, `16931` = 9L, `1715` = 12L, `13552` = 7L, `233` = 11L, 
    `14184` = 7L, `8058` = 1L, `14137` = 7L, `2311` = 2L, `5323` = 2L, 
    `4644` = 2L, `6574` = 1L, `17585` = 10L, `16978` = 9L, `13097` = 6L, 
    `1034` = 12L, `17359` = 9L, `11186` = 4L, `16289` = 8L, `3544` = 2L, 
    `17221` = 9L, `17241` = 9L, `15320` = 8L, `10361` = 4L, `1179` = 12L, 
    `14696` = 7L, `14240` = 7L, `13281` = 6L, `188` = 11L, `8918` = 3L, 
    `4295` = 2L, `13565` = 7L, `9686` = 4L, `7499` = 1L, `9813` = 4L, 
    `13569` = 7L, `8581` = 3L, `11029` = 4L, `16300` = 8L, `12477` = 6L, 
    `9374` = 3L, `9036` = 3L, `13522` = 6L, `10031` = 4L, `821` = 12L, 
    `10016` = 4L, `11970` = 5L, `6923` = 1L, `13808` = 7L, `9402` = 3L, 
    `14592` = 7L, `8781` = 3L, `2527` = 2L, `4597` = 2L, `4885` = 2L, 
    `1247` = 12L, `5828` = 2L), .Label = c("ADC1", "ADC10_caucasian", 
    "ADC2", "ADC3", "ADC4", "ADC5", "ADC6", "ADC7", "ADC8", "ADC8_hispanic", 
    "ADC9_AA", "ADC9_caucasian"), class = "factor"), merged_id = structure(c(`4367` = 21L, 
    `15178` = 86L, `803` = 1L, `7231` = 37L, `3314` = 17L, `6567` = 31L, 
    `11534` = 59L, `11544` = 60L, `5371` = 28L, `15551` = 89L, 
    `15391` = 88L, `14921` = 84L, `15665` = 90L, `14068` = 77L, 
    `9859` = 52L, `9353` = 47L, `7324` = 38L, `10566` = 56L, 
    `6686` = 33L, `12009` = 62L, `14927` = 85L, `14565` = 81L, 
    `5654` = 29L, `13417` = 70L, `6817` = 35L, `3028` = 16L, 
    `4108` = 19L, `17234` = 98L, `8051` = 40L, `13970` = 76L, 
    `17705` = 8L, `12823` = 66L, `5180` = 26L, `12413` = 63L, 
    `4861` = 24L, `16204` = 91L, `17781` = 10L, `8091` = 42L, 
    `13260` = 68L, `16577` = 94L, `2947` = 15L, `12549` = 65L, 
    `6698` = 34L, `1921` = 12L, `16931` = 95L, `1715` = 11L, 
    `13552` = 72L, `233` = 9L, `14184` = 79L, `8058` = 41L, `14137` = 78L, 
    `2311` = 13L, `5323` = 27L, `4644` = 23L, `6574` = 32L, `17585` = 3L, 
    `16978` = 96L, `13097` = 67L, `1034` = 4L, `17359` = 100L, 
    `11186` = 58L, `16289` = 92L, `3544` = 18L, `17221` = 97L, 
    `17241` = 99L, `15320` = 87L, `10361` = 55L, `1179` = 5L, 
    `14696` = 83L, `14240` = 80L, `13281` = 69L, `188` = 7L, 
    `8918` = 45L, `4295` = 20L, `13565` = 73L, `9686` = 50L, 
    `7499` = 39L, `9813` = 51L, `13569` = 74L, `8581` = 43L, 
    `11029` = 57L, `16300` = 93L, `12477` = 64L, `9374` = 48L, 
    `9036` = 46L, `13522` = 71L, `10031` = 54L, `821` = 2L, `10016` = 53L, 
    `11970` = 61L, `6923` = 36L, `13808` = 75L, `9402` = 49L, 
    `14592` = 82L, `8781` = 44L, `2527` = 14L, `4597` = 22L, 
    `4885` = 25L, `1247` = 6L, `5828` = 30L), .Label = c("0_NACC224051", 
    "0_NACC234892", "0_NACC246522", "0_NACC358132", "0_NACC459177", 
    "0_NACC492224", "0_NACC512892", "0_NACC529473", "0_NACC618811", 
    "0_NACC722553", "0_NACC753447", "0_NACC889512", "1191_NACC119655", 
    "1377_NACC183751", "1735_NACC293642", "1805_NACC456139", 
    "2057_NACC984280", "2274_NACC483309", "2793_NACC038726", 
    "2965_NACC992021", "3028_NACC302216", "3239_NACC022113", 
    "3281_NACC286235", "3480_NACC726530", "3501_NACC522588", 
    "443_NACC171578", "566_NACC795252", "604_NACC843642", "842_NACC956562", 
    "993_NACC717532", "ADC1_09AD16914_NACC082679_09AD16914_NACC082679", 
    "ADC1_09AD16934_NACC444662_09AD16934_NACC444662", "ADC1_NACC035702_08AD11678_NACC035702_08AD11678", 
    "ADC1_NACC039815_09AD14641_NACC039815_09AD14641", "ADC1_NACC105660_08AD11689_NACC105660_08AD11689", 
    "ADC1_NACC151854_08AD7757_NACC151854_08AD7757", "ADC1_NACC333589_09AD13683_NACC333589_09AD13683", 
    "ADC1_NACC380482_08AD8144_NACC380482_08AD8144", "ADC1_NACC466486_08AD10812_NACC466486_08AD10812", 
    "ADC1_NACC735204_08AD11164_NACC735204_08AD11164", "ADC1_NACC737878_08AD11016_NACC737878_08AD11016", 
    "ADC1_NACC752488_08AD7749_NACC752488_08AD7749", "ADC2_NACC006368_NACC006368", 
    "ADC2_NACC250984_NACC250984", "ADC2_NACC386821_NACC386821", 
    "ADC2_NACC510923_NACC510923", "ADC2_NACC842938_NACC842938", 
    "ADC2_NACC864182_NACC864182", "ADC2_NACC893727_NACC893727", 
    "ADC3_09AD15049_09AD15049", "ADC3_09AD16760_09AD16760", "ADC3_09AD17380_09AD17380", 
    "ADC3_09AD18901_09AD18901", "ADC3_09AD18925_09AD18925", "ADC3_09AD19739_09AD19739", 
    "ADC3_09AD20369_09AD20369", "ADC3_10AD23300_10AD23300", "ADC3_27564_27564", 
    "ADC4_NACC256669_NACC256669", "ADC4_NACC266210_NACC266210", 
    "ADC4_NACC670026_NACC670026", "ADC4_NACC708345_NACC708345", 
    "ADC5_NACC079667_NACC079667", "ADC5_NACC135096_NACC135096", 
    "ADC5_NACC191953_NACC191953", "ADC5_NACC417504_NACC417504", 
    "ADC5_NACC636234_NACC636234", "ADC5_NACC770057_NACC770057", 
    "ADC5_NACC794979_NACC794979", "ADC5_NACC907646_NACC907646", 
    "ADC5_NACC982981_NACC982981", "ADC6_NACC006109_NACC006109", 
    "ADC6_NACC017525_NACC017525", "ADC6_NACC024542_NACC024542", 
    "ADC6_NACC209283_NACC209283", "ADC6_NACC322567_NACC322567", 
    "ADC6_NACC392815_NACC392815", "ADC6_NACC448017_NACC448017", 
    "ADC6_NACC484535_NACC484535", "ADC6_NACC514998_NACC514998", 
    "ADC6_NACC780374_NACC780374", "ADC6_NACC795728_NACC795728", 
    "ADC6_NACC864553_NACC864553", "ADC7_NACC025848_NACC025848", 
    "ADC7_NACC031468_NACC031468", "ADC7_NACC195165_NACC195165", 
    "ADC7_NACC306292_NACC306292", "ADC7_NACC347611_NACC347611", 
    "ADC7_NACC472939_NACC472939", "ADC7_NACC553874_NACC553874", 
    "ADC7_NACC896900_NACC896900", "ADC7_NACC963831_NACC963831", 
    "ADC7_NACC971672_NACC971672", "ADC8_NACC193689_NACC193689", 
    "ADC8_NACC522704_NACC522704", "ADC8_NACC575784_NACC575784", 
    "ADC8_NACC788939_NACC788939", "ADC8_NACC799353_NACC799353", 
    "ADC8_NACC804511_NACC804511", "ADC8_NACC898988_NACC898988"
    ), class = "factor"), omit = structure(c(`4367` = 1L, `15178` = 1L, 
    `803` = 1L, `7231` = 1L, `3314` = 1L, `6567` = 2L, `11534` = 1L, 
    `11544` = 2L, `5371` = 1L, `15551` = 1L, `15391` = 1L, `14921` = 1L, 
    `15665` = 1L, `14068` = 2L, `9859` = 1L, `9353` = 1L, `7324` = 1L, 
    `10566` = 1L, `6686` = 1L, `12009` = 2L, `14927` = 1L, `14565` = 2L, 
    `5654` = 1L, `13417` = 1L, `6817` = 1L, `3028` = 1L, `4108` = 2L, 
    `17234` = 1L, `8051` = 1L, `13970` = 2L, `17705` = 1L, `12823` = 2L, 
    `5180` = 2L, `12413` = 2L, `4861` = 1L, `16204` = 1L, `17781` = 1L, 
    `8091` = 1L, `13260` = 1L, `16577` = 1L, `2947` = 1L, `12549` = 1L, 
    `6698` = 1L, `1921` = 1L, `16931` = 1L, `1715` = 1L, `13552` = 2L, 
    `233` = 1L, `14184` = 2L, `8058` = 1L, `14137` = 1L, `2311` = 2L, 
    `5323` = 1L, `4644` = 1L, `6574` = 1L, `17585` = 1L, `16978` = 1L, 
    `13097` = 1L, `1034` = 1L, `17359` = 1L, `11186` = 2L, `16289` = 1L, 
    `3544` = 1L, `17221` = 1L, `17241` = 1L, `15320` = 1L, `10361` = 1L, 
    `1179` = 1L, `14696` = 1L, `14240` = 1L, `13281` = 1L, `188` = 1L, 
    `8918` = 1L, `4295` = 1L, `13565` = 2L, `9686` = 1L, `7499` = 1L, 
    `9813` = 1L, `13569` = 1L, `8581` = 1L, `11029` = 1L, `16300` = 1L, 
    `12477` = 1L, `9374` = 1L, `9036` = 2L, `13522` = 2L, `10031` = 1L, 
    `821` = 1L, `10016` = 1L, `11970` = 1L, `6923` = 2L, `13808` = 2L, 
    `9402` = 1L, `14592` = 2L, `8781` = 1L, `2527` = 1L, `4597` = 1L, 
    `4885` = 1L, `1247` = 1L, `5828` = 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"
    ), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 
    1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c(" 1", " 2", "-9"), class = "factor"), 
    status = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c(" 1", " 2", " 3", "-9"), class = "factor"), 
    age_at_onset = structure(c(`4367` = 22L, `15178` = NA, `803` = 4L, 
    `7231` = 12L, `3314` = 23L, `6567` = NA, `11534` = 11L, `11544` = NA, 
    `5371` = 1L, `15551` = 12L, `15391` = NA, `14921` = 5L, `15665` = NA, 
    `14068` = NA, `9859` = 7L, `9353` = 16L, `7324` = 7L, `10566` = NA, 
    `6686` = 6L, `12009` = NA, `14927` = 3L, `14565` = NA, `5654` = 24L, 
    `13417` = NA, `6817` = 3L, `3028` = 2L, `4108` = 21L, `17234` = NA, 
    `8051` = 14L, `13970` = NA, `17705` = 14L, `12823` = NA, 
    `5180` = NA, `12413` = NA, `4861` = 21L, `16204` = NA, `17781` = NA, 
    `8091` = 25L, `13260` = 20L, `16577` = 9L, `2947` = 6L, `12549` = NA, 
    `6698` = NA, `1921` = 5L, `16931` = 10L, `1715` = NA, `13552` = NA, 
    `233` = NA, `14184` = NA, `8058` = NA, `14137` = NA, `2311` = 17L, 
    `5323` = 22L, `4644` = NA, `6574` = NA, `17585` = NA, `16978` = NA, 
    `13097` = NA, `1034` = 20L, `17359` = 13L, `11186` = NA, 
    `16289` = NA, `3544` = 17L, `17221` = 16L, `17241` = NA, 
    `15320` = NA, `10361` = 19L, `1179` = 23L, `14696` = NA, 
    `14240` = NA, `13281` = NA, `188` = NA, `8918` = NA, `4295` = 8L, 
    `13565` = NA, `9686` = 11L, `7499` = 19L, `9813` = 9L, `13569` = 15L, 
    `8581` = NA, `11029` = 23L, `16300` = NA, `12477` = NA, `9374` = NA, 
    `9036` = NA, `13522` = NA, `10031` = 7L, `821` = NA, `10016` = NA, 
    `11970` = 14L, `6923` = NA, `13808` = NA, `9402` = 18L, `14592` = NA, 
    `8781` = NA, `2527` = 11L, `4597` = NA, `4885` = NA, `1247` = NA, 
    `5828` = 23L), .Label = c("54", "58", "60", "61", "63", "64", 
    "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "74", "75", 
    "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "84", "88", "90"), class = "factor"), 
    age_last_visit = structure(c(`4367` = 25L, `15178` = 13L, 
    `803` = 5L, `7231` = NA, `3314` = 29L, `6567` = NA, `11534` = 17L, 
    `11544` = NA, `5371` = 8L, `15551` = 22L, `15391` = 21L, 
    `14921` = 5L, `15665` = 13L, `14068` = NA, `9859` = NA, `9353` = 29L, 
    `7324` = NA, `10566` = 26L, `6686` = NA, `12009` = NA, `14927` = 4L, 
    `14565` = NA, `5654` = 32L, `13417` = 3L, `6817` = NA, `3028` = 5L, 
    `4108` = 25L, `17234` = 14L, `8051` = NA, `13970` = NA, `17705` = 20L, 
    `12823` = NA, `5180` = 26L, `12413` = NA, `4861` = 24L, `16204` = 1L, 
    `17781` = 9L, `8091` = NA, `13260` = 30L, `16577` = 12L, 
    `2947` = 12L, `12549` = 12L, `6698` = NA, `1921` = 10L, `16931` = 9L, 
    `1715` = 10L, `13552` = NA, `233` = 15L, `14184` = NA, `8058` = NA, 
    `14137` = 8L, `2311` = 28L, `5323` = 31L, `4644` = 21L, `6574` = 2L, 
    `17585` = 6L, `16978` = 8L, `13097` = 13L, `1034` = 23L, 
    `17359` = 16L, `11186` = NA, `16289` = 12L, `3544` = 26L, 
    `17221` = 22L, `17241` = 21L, `15320` = 14L, `10361` = NA, 
    `1179` = 25L, `14696` = 17L, `14240` = 7L, `13281` = 21L, 
    `188` = 11L, `8918` = 21L, `4295` = 12L, `13565` = NA, `9686` = NA, 
    `7499` = NA, `9813` = NA, `13569` = 19L, `8581` = 14L, `11029` = 27L, 
    `16300` = 19L, `12477` = 8L, `9374` = 19L, `9036` = NA, `13522` = NA, 
    `10031` = 16L, `821` = 18L, `10016` = 5L, `11970` = 16L, 
    `6923` = NA, `13808` = NA, `9402` = 28L, `14592` = NA, `8781` = 26L, 
    `2527` = 13L, `4597` = 6L, `4885` = 12L, `1247` = 11L, `5828` = 33L
    ), .Label = c("61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
    "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", 
    "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", 
    "89", "90", "91", "93", "95"), class = "factor"), age_at_death = structure(c(`4367` = NA, 
    `15178` = NA, `803` = NA, `7231` = 4L, `3314` = NA, `6567` = NA, 
    `11534` = NA, `11544` = NA, `5371` = 2L, `15551` = NA, `15391` = NA, 
    `14921` = NA, `15665` = NA, `14068` = NA, `9859` = 6L, `9353` = NA, 
    `7324` = 8L, `10566` = NA, `6686` = 13L, `12009` = NA, `14927` = NA, 
    `14565` = NA, `5654` = 14L, `13417` = NA, `6817` = 9L, `3028` = 1L, 
    `4108` = 12L, `17234` = NA, `8051` = 5L, `13970` = NA, `17705` = NA, 
    `12823` = NA, `5180` = NA, `12413` = NA, `4861` = NA, `16204` = NA, 
    `17781` = NA, `8091` = 14L, `13260` = NA, `16577` = 6L, `2947` = NA, 
    `12549` = NA, `6698` = 10L, `1921` = 3L, `16931` = NA, `1715` = NA, 
    `13552` = NA, `233` = NA, `14184` = NA, `8058` = 3L, `14137` = NA, 
    `2311` = NA, `5323` = 15L, `4644` = NA, `6574` = NA, `17585` = NA, 
    `16978` = NA, `13097` = NA, `1034` = NA, `17359` = 9L, `11186` = NA, 
    `16289` = NA, `3544` = NA, `17221` = NA, `17241` = NA, `15320` = NA, 
    `10361` = 11L, `1179` = 13L, `14696` = NA, `14240` = NA, 
    `13281` = NA, `188` = NA, `8918` = NA, `4295` = NA, `13565` = NA, 
    `9686` = 11L, `7499` = 11L, `9813` = 8L, `13569` = NA, `8581` = NA, 
    `11029` = NA, `16300` = NA, `12477` = NA, `9374` = NA, `9036` = NA, 
    `13522` = NA, `10031` = NA, `821` = NA, `10016` = NA, `11970` = NA, 
    `6923` = NA, `13808` = NA, `9402` = NA, `14592` = NA, `8781` = NA, 
    `2527` = 7L, `4597` = NA, `4885` = NA, `1247` = NA, `5828` = NA
    ), .Label = c("67", "68", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", 
    "77", "78", "84", "85", "86", "93", "94"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("4367", 
"15178", "803", "7231", "3314", "6567", "11534", "11544", "5371", 
"15551", "15391", "14921", "15665", "14068", "9859", "9353", 
"7324", "10566", "6686", "12009", "14927", "14565", "5654", "13417", 
"6817", "3028", "4108", "17234", "8051", "13970", "17705", "12823", 
"5180", "12413", "4861", "16204", "17781", "8091", "13260", "16577", 
"2947", "12549", "6698", "1921", "16931", "1715", "13552", "233", 
"14184", "8058", "14137", "2311", "5323", "4644", "6574", "17585", 
"16978", "13097", "1034", "17359", "11186", "16289", "3544", 
"17221", "17241", "15320", "10361", "1179", "14696", "14240", 
"13281", "188", "8918", "4295", "13565", "9686", "7499", "9813", 
"13569", "8581", "11029", "16300", "12477", "9374", "9036", "13522", 
"10031", "821", "10016", "11970", "6923", "13808", "9402", "14592", 
"8781", "2527", "4597", "4885", "1247", "5828"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be better answered in stackoverflow, but I'm guessing you are more concerned with answering what they mean by stratify yes?

I'm guessing they want you to create age groups and then you'll have multi dimensional tables from this. One table for each group you stratify by.

Here's how to create age groups in decades. Not the most elegant solution, but it will do. I just assumed you wanted `age_last_visit`

```
tt$age_last_visit<- as.numeric(as.character(tt$age_last_visit))
tt$Age_decades<- cut(tt$age_last_visit, breaks = c(seq(0, 100, by = 10), Inf))
tt$Age_decades_numeric <-ifelse(tt$Age_decades=="(10,20]",1, ifelse(tt$Age_decades== "(20,30]" ,2,ifelse(tt$Age_decades=="(30,40]",3, ifelse(tt$Age_decades== "(40,50]", 4, ifelse(tt$Age_decades== "(50,60]", 5, ifelse(tt$Age_decades=="(60,70]", 6, ifelse(tt$Age_decades== "(70,80]", 7, ifelse(tt$Age_decades=="(80,90]",8,NA))))))))
```

Then stratify with this

```
table(tt$Age_decades, tt$cohort, tt$status)
```

I recommend making the splits on the variable with the `fewest` levels/values it can take which is `status` in this case. If you want more elegant tables I highly recommend the `table1` package in R. Very high quality html tables